# Maximizing product of exponential functions

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I am trying to find the Maximum of the following function with respect to variable b1. 
I use Mathematica to find the derivative and set it equal to zero. but its derivative w.r.t b1 is very complicated and I cannot get b1. (even I am not sure this function is concave?)
I really appreciate if you could help me.

All my parameters in the model (b1,b2,B,v,w1,w2,D1,D2,q1,q2) are positive.

$[\frac{b1(B-b1)v}{1-b1w1-(B-b1)w2+b1(B-b1)v}e^{((-q1/b1)-(q2/(B-b1)))}]*[(D1.e^{(q1/b1)}-1).(D2.e^{(q2/(B-b1))}-1)]$

Comment: Why not maximizing the logarithm of this function which looks a little simpler ?

Comment: In this case, a Monte Carlo simulation might give you an idea of where are the possible extremas of this function.

Comment: I tried "maximizing the logarithm", but its still hard to get the extreme point, since, in the last two expressions, there is: "ln(exp(.)-1)" which will make logarithm problematic as well.

Comment: I am thinking of applying special rules, for example, the two expressions in the last [] are monotonic decreasing and increasing respectively. I am wondering about using such rules in case applicable here.

Comment: Try to plot it for different values of the parameters. You will probably be surprised...

Comment: One thing is certain : in practical applications such as this one : max and min are **almost never** found by equating the derivative to zero... They are found for example by optimization methods

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. Do you mean using numerical methods? I am looking for some exact max value if there is any.

Comment: IMHO, seeing your expression, it is a little desperate. I might be wrong...